# Zend Framework 1.11 - CSS not rendering for header.phtml , footer.phtml

Tags: zend-framework

My problem is related to partial files in zend layout. Here is my directory structure

[image]

Content of admin.html is as below

[image]

And application.ini is as follows :
[image]

Now the problem is the css for admin_header.phtml and admin_footer.phtml is not rendering. The layout is able to include files but css is not working for included files. CSS is working for rest of layout except header and footer. I'll appreciate if someone help me on this.

Comment: Nothing to help with, it should work. Check paths and spelling and make sure your selectors are correct.

Comment: Do you have a 'public' folder in your application? If so you need to move your assets folder into that. If not - where is your index.php and .htaccess file? As those are not in your screenshot of the file structure.

Comment: when you say "CSS is working for rest of layout except header and footer" what specifically do you mean by that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there was a path mismatch in my css. its working now. thanks all.